# Funcionamiento de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Según entiendo, al crear una variable, estamos creando un objeto, y el nombre de la variable referencia al mismo.

Si yo hago:

```
a = 2
a = "Hola"
```

El garbage collector se encarga de borrar el objeto 2, ya que no lo necesita y ninguna otra variable lo está referenciando en el programa. En cambio si escribo:

```
a = 2
b = a
a = "Hola"
```

Al estar b referenciando al objeto 2, ahora tengo los dos objetos en memoria, y ninguno de los dos es eliminado.

¿Estoy en lo correcto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Efectivamente, Python no utiliza los punteros que conocemos en otros lenguajes que referencian los objetos y los modifican desde distintos puntos del programa con variables relacionadas. Puedes probar esto que dices: https://repl.it/FqK7/0 Te dejo un ejemplo en GO de como funcionan los punteros. https://play.golang.org/p/Zs_Szx9Dch

Comment: Prácticamente en cualquier lenguaje las variables se sobrescriben al declararlas con el mismo nombre que previamente se nombraron. Internamente efectúa un replace.value mas que un borrar y crear variable. Esto lo hace por eficiencia como te lo han dicho muy bien con el ejemplo de los compañeros, "tema de punteros".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Un consejo: en python no pienses en objetos que se crean o destruyen, más bien piensa en objetos a los que accedes a través de su nombre, una mera etiqueta con la que indicas al intérprete lo que tiene que hacer.

Todo lo que veas sobre *"creación de variables"* o *"asignación de variables"* es herencia de cómo se pensaba en otros lenguajes. En python se *"dan nombres"*.

Por seguir tu ejemplo:

```
a = 2
a = "Hola"
```

Al objeto de tipo *entero* `2` lo identificamos con el nombre `a`. Luego, al objeto *string* `"Hola"` lo identificamos con el nombre `a`. Lo único que puedes asegurar ahora es que el nombre `a` identifica la cadena `"Hola"`; no puedes saber qué ha pasado con el objeto `2`. Es posible que estuviera referenciando con otro nombre y que no se pueda borrar. También es posible que, al ser un objeto tan común, siempre esté disponible en memoria. En python, todos los números desde -5 al 256 existen en memoria, aunque nadie los use, por motivos de optimización.

Una forma de confirmarlo:

```
[i for i in range(-100,300) if id(i)==id(i+0)]
```

`id()` devuelve un identificador único para cada objeto. Si dos objetos tienen el mismo identificador, es que son el mismo objeto.

Con las cadenas pasa algo más curioso:

```
id("hola2")==id("hola"+"2")  # -> True
id("hola 2")==id("hola "+"2") # -> False
```

Este comportamiento se corresponde con un proceso automático de *"internalización de cadenas"* empleado en la optimizaciones del intérprete. Este proceso mete en una caché todas las cadenas de caracteres presentes en el código que cumplan con la reglas de nombrado de variables. En el caso anterior, `hola2` podría servir como nombre de una variables, `hola 2` no. Toda cadena *internalizada* nunca será *borrada*, aunque no sea referenciada.

Por concluir, veamos el último caso:

```
a = 2
b = a
a = "Hola"
```

Aquí, lo que se hace es dar otro nombre, `b` al objeto que apuntaba `a`. Nada se crea, nada se destruye.

Entrando a más bajo nivel, no es el GC el que destruye los objetos. Los objetos tienen un contador de referencias de modo que, cuando este contador llega a cero, se autodestruyen.

El GC es un instrumento que tiene el intérprete para liberar memoria en determinados casos complejos de detectar, como son las *referencias circulares*:

```
a = []
b = [a]
a.append(b)
del a
del b
```

Aquí hemos creado dos listas que se autoreferencian y luego hemos borrado nuestras referencias. Aunque no tengamos forma ya de acceder a estas listas, entre ellas se están referenciando, por lo que sus contadores de referencias nunca llegan a cero. Tiene que ser el GC quién se encargue de comprobar que no hay ningún otro objeto que las necesite y las elimine de memoria.

Comment: Solo por añadir algo complementario a esta magnífica respuesta: puedes utilizar  http://pythontutor.com/ para entender mejor el funcionamiento. Ejecuta los códigos de ejemplo que propone ChemCortes.

Comment: No conocía [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com). Es una forma genial de entender visualemente cómo funciona python.

Answer (score 1):

**tu primer ejemplo:**

```
a = 2  variable `a` almacenando 2
a = "Hola" ahora a almacena "HOLA"
```

> tienes una variable por que es la misma variable, cambiando de valor
>   de 2 a "HOLA". solamente puede existir dos o mas variables con el mismo nombre con diferente alcance.

**tu segundo ejemplo**

```
a = 2 // variable `a` almacenando 2
b = a // variable `b` almacenando el valor actual de la variable `a`(el valor es 2)
a = "Hola" // ahora la variable a almacena "HOLA"
```

> Al estar b referenciando al objeto 2, ahora tengo los dos objetos en
>   memoria, y ninguno de los dos es eliminado.

respondiendo a tu pregunta: tienes dos variables a, b por que tienen distintos nombres.